# Making a new column in r with counts

Tags: r

I have the following matrix in R

```
b = matrix(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2), ncol = 1)
```

I execute the following command to count all of the unique values.

```
table(b)
```

I actually want to know what command I should execute to get a column with all of the values and next to it a column with the count of each value as follows.

```
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1   12
 [2,]    1   12
 [3,]    1   12
 [4,]    1   12
 [5,]    1   12
 [6,]    1   12
 [7,]    1   12
 [8,]    1   12
 [9,]    1   12
[10,]    1   12
[11,]    1   12
[12,]    1   12
[13,]    2    1
```

Comment: For code blocks, indent four spaces or use the button like {} at the top of the editor.

Answer (score 5):

We can use `ave`

```
cbind(b, ave(b[,1], b[,1], FUN=length))
#       [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1   12
# [2,]    1   12
# [3,]    1   12
# [4,]    1   12
# [5,]    1   12
# [6,]    1   12
# [7,]    1   12
# [8,]    1   12
# [9,]    1   12
#[10,]    1   12
#[11,]    1   12
#[12,]    1   12
#[13,]    2    1
```

Comment: @Mol Suppose if you want to create a new column in a dataset by some grouping variables, `ave` can be used.  It is not `subset`ing, but it can be useful for subsetting by returning  logical index (if needed).